# Cannot install plugins

Tags: plugins

I'm getting an error message `Installation failed: Could not create directory.`

How can I solve this? Also, where do I find the installation path on Wordpress?
[image]

Comment: Please check **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157264/wordpress-plugin-install-could-not-create-directory**

Comment: Hi @PratikPatel is there a way to do it from Wordpress itself?

Comment: you need to change permissions of your plugin directory. no you can't do it from wordpress itself, you need to do it thru FTP.

Comment: @John, No u have to give permission to your plugin folder manually using FTP

Comment: upload plugin in your plugin folder through FTP and give permission to that folder through FTP